# What strategy would you go with when implementing Linkedin auth on a website that has already registered users?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, linkedin-api

We already have a working website with registered users and I have the task to implement the LinkedIn authentication into our website and we are using MongoDB and mongoose.

I already did everything I needed to do with the Linkedin API and I am getting the email of the user who signed in with his/her LinkedIn account.
Once the user logs in, the server gets the email and check if it the user associated to that email already exists. If it exists then send the JWT token if not then create a new user and then send the JWT token, but in order to create the new user we need to have the password since it is a required field in the user schema, and we are only getting the email, first and last name, no password.

How would you go about this? Should I get rid of the password required field and then simply check if there is a password in the login and signup route? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Just put any random (really random if you care) password there. It doesn't require any changes and lets user to reset the password if they prefer.

Comment: So you mean I should use any randomly generated password? This won't cause any security issues right? Sorry I am a newbie and do not know much about security

Comment: Then you have 3 options - learn, ask somebody to do, leave it up to a random guy in the Internet to decide for you. It's not rocket science and if you implemented single sign on with linkedin OpenID Connect the idea of random password should be quite simple to grock. Unless your random password generator is not like this https://xkcd.com/22 it's no worse than user's generated password.

Comment: As Alex Blex here said to generate just a random password and just update it when the user is creating the new password, If you still think this might cause any securities issue(IT WON'T) you can simply add another field in your DB say 'newPasswordCreated` and set it FALSE. Set this to TRUE only when the user has created their password. Reject Login for all user's for whom this field is FALSE.